# create new content link in the view list page

Tags: views

I need your help for the following things:

1.i have a content type called "discussion-topics",**Discussion-board** is the view  created for this Content type.I want to show   create new content link in the view list page .

It is a discussion board page and an authenticated user can only create the new entry to this board.

Do we have any option to show ***create new link*** in View settings ?Please reply me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: add create link in views header widget.

Comment: How can we add a link in view's header widget?

Comment: solved with Views link area  module.
How can i set an admin approval option to each user entries?

Comment: How can I approve a user's blog/node entry before it's posted?
I found modr8 ,but its for D6,i'm using D7...